# How to disable current-chapter numbers in cross references, but not in theorem heads

Tags: cross-referencing

I am editing a big book using Springer's \documentclass{svmono}.
In cross referencing, I disable appearance of current-chapter number
by putting the following lines in the main file

\renewcommand\thetheorem{\maybe{\arabic{chapter}}\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\maybe[1]{\ifnum#1=\value{chapter}\relax\else\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}.\fi}

As a side effect, chapter numbers disappeared in heads of theorem-like environments.
The author asks to retain them there. For example in Chapter IV, say, in print we need

*Theorem IV.3.2 Text of the theorem.*

and later in the same chapter:

*See Theorem 3.2 for ....*

Can anybody help to achieve this, preferably without new packages?